# Polyglossia - Italic in Hebrew

Tags: xetex, fontspec, polyglossia, hebrew

I am new to LaTeX and I just strated to use Polyglossia to write Hebrew documents. When I try to write text in italic, it just produces the same text style. For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setmainfont{David}

\begin{document}
שלום עולם

\textit{שלום עולם}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]

How can I define italic-type for the font?

Comment: Maybe *David* does not have an italic variant (or you don't have it installed). Try *David CLM* from http://culmus.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I downloaded it using this link: http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~sameti/tex/culmusmiktex.html for Windows, but it doesn't seem to be working... When trying to write in italic variant it just says that the file is not found.David CLM exists, but its italic variant doesn't.

Comment: Italics aren't really used in hebrew typesetting. Some people do letterspacing (which I suggest against). There is a way to fake it, though. You can use the AutoFakeSlant option with a negative number when you use the font. Although that's also arguably a bad idea.

Comment: Make sure what you downloaded includes *David CLM* in OpenType format and it is installed as a system font so it appears in other applications (e.g., Word).

Comment: Actually, you definitely *don't* want that MikTeX download. I does not include any OpenType fonts, only formats for use with `pdflatex`. You want to download the latest release from SourceForge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/culmus/files/culmus/0.133/

Comment: Thanks! I'll try downloading it.

Comment: I've tried installing culmus from their site, as you advised me to do, mutliple times, but I can't figure out how; it just gives me a tar.gz file and I'm using Windows so I can't unpack it. I also have a linux machine but I'm not planning on moving to Linux just to run culmus. Do you know how to install it?

Comment: @ABN263 in order to open tar.gz files on Windows you can use 7zip.

Comment: I am sorry for these technical help questions, but how do I install it after unpacking the file? There is a collection of fonts and other files there; how do I install it?

Comment: @ABN263 right-click on the font file and select `Install`

Comment: culmus is abandonware, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Use a font that supports Hebrew italics, such as the Culmus fonts:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[bidi=default, english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{parskip}

\babelprovide[import, main]{hebrew}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Ligatures = TeX, Scale = MatchUppercase }
\babelfont{rm}[Scale = 1.0, Ligatures = Common, Language = Default]{TeX Gyre Bonum}
\babelfont{sf}[Ligatures = Common, Language = Default]{TeX Gyre Heros}
\babelfont{tt}[Language = Default]{Inconsolatazi4}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Language = Default]{David CLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}[Language = Default]{Miriam CLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{tt}[Language = Default]{Miriam Mono CLM}

\begin{document}
שלום עולם

\textit{שלום עולם}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This particular font slants its italic face right-to-left.  If you would rather slant left-to-right (matching the Latin script and many Israeli word processors), instead use `FakeSlant`.  Here, I’ve defined this as the slanted font (`\slshape` or `\textsl`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[bidi=default, english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{parskip}

\babelprovide[import, main]{hebrew}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Ligatures = TeX, Scale = MatchUppercase }
\defaultfontfeatures[DavidCLM]{
  UprightFont = {*-Medium},
  BoldFont = {*-Bold},
  SlantedFont = {*-Medium},
  BoldSlantedFont = {*-Bold},
  SlantedFeatures = {FakeSlant = 0.15},
  Extension = {.otf}
}

\babelfont{rm}[Scale = 1.0, Ligatures = Common, Language = Default]{TeX Gyre Bonum}
\babelfont{sf}[Ligatures = Common, Language = Default]{TeX Gyre Heros}
\babelfont{tt}[Language = Default]{Inconsolatazi4}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Language = Default]{DavidCLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}[Language = Default]{Miriam CLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{tt}[Language = Default]{Miriam Mono CLM}

\begin{document}
שלום עולם

\textsl{שלום עולם}
\end{document}
```

[image: David CLM sample]

Answer (score 0):

This works as it should on a stable Debian system - although
I had to use `\setmainfont{David CLM}` instead of `\setmainfont{David}`
(there is no `David` font available in Debian, only `David CLM`)